# Android чтение файла doc

Tags: java, android

Как прочитать файл созданный программно. Я пытаюсь чтобы пользователь открыл его любой установленной для этого программой(из "application/msword"). Я так полагаю что доступа к файлу нет, так как его получить (чтобы он был открыт для всех). Или я не правильно его пытаюсь открыть ?

```
public class word extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnSave, btnLoad;
String filename = "xxx.doc";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_word);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoad);

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("WorldWriteableFiles")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Word");
            boolean success = true;
            success = folder.mkdir();
            String filePath = folder.toString();
            try
            {
                WordDocument doc = new WordDocument();
                Run run = new Run();
                run.addText("Hello Word!");
                Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
                paragraph.add(run);
                doc.getBody().add(paragraph);
                doc.save(filePath+"/"+filename, true);
                              } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    btnLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Word");
            String filePath = folder.toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(filePath+"/"+filename));
            intent.setType("application/msword");
            Intent chosenIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Выбрать програму..");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(chosenIntent);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Файл чтение "+filePath+"--"+filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: а что не получается? открыть файл или вы его просто не видите?

Comment: Файл как и директория создается, я его вижу, через total commander  ADB однако открыть его не получается... приложение просит сохранить файл на устройстве .. хотя в папке файл есть ? в манифесте все прописано.. Такое ощущение, что надо в атрибуте файла нужно установить полный доступ, как это сделать я не знаю...

Comment: если я его вытаскиваю из папки эмулятора то он открывается ..

Comment: то есть на эмуляторе все работает нормально?

Comment: Нет  кода я на комп копирую файл из папки "/storage/emulated/0/download/Word/xxx.doc" то файл читает все ОК, однако программно  на android не читает word просит   Try saving on device and then opening it. Другая программа чтения doc вылетает ..

Comment: вы не можете передавать через Intent путь